# What happens when we cast char to a number greater than 256?

Tags: c++, casting

I created a program that could create 256 unique symbols, and it works fine. It works by writing to binary the (char) cast of 1-256. But if I decide to print (char)257 to the file, the file still has 256 unique symbols. When I cout (char)257, I don't see anything on the screen. Is this just a empty character or does it actually point to something?

Also if ASCII is 128 letters, what would you call the term for 256 characters? UTF-8?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you cast `257` to `char`, the value is truncated to 1.

Assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4 in your platform, `257` is represented as `0x00000101` in hex. When you truncate that to a `char` by performing a cast, you get `0x01`, which is equal to `1`. The ASCII character represented by `1` is not a printable character. Hence, you don't see any output when you use:

```
std::cout << (char)257;
```

If you use:

```
char c = (char)257;
std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;
```

You should see `1` as the output.

> what would you call the term for 256 characters?

I believe you are talking about the [extended ASCII characters](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Comment: Thank you! Learned something today!

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'cast `char` to a number'. You can *cast a number to `char`,* but then what you get is the `char,` which isn't wide enough to hold a number greater than 255.

Comment: Thanks. I still hope I got my message across.